# How to check if an image is flipped or not with respect to base image

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

In OpenCV I can flip the image horizontally and vertically using this code :

```
import cv2
img=cv2.imread('1.png')
rimg=img.copy()
fimg=img.copy()
rimg=cv2.flip(img,1)
fimg=cv2.flip(img,0)
cv2.imshow("Original", img)
cv2.imshow("vertical flip", rimg)
cv2.imshow("horizontal flip", fimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My question is: is there any way to check that the input image is flipped with respect to the base image? I just want to know the steps to check if the image is flipped or not.

Comment: In general, no. If the image is not symmetric in some fashion, then you can probably just flip along different axises and do a quick comparison to check if `np.any` are non-equal.

Comment: I guess you could maybe sum the pixels in the top row, the bottom row, left edge and right edge (separately) and compare the edges with your reference image.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pseudo c++ solution:

```
bool isSameSize(Image a, Image b)
{
    return a.width() == b.width() && a.height() == b.height();
}
bool isNotFlipped(Image a, Image b)
{
    if(!isSameSize(a, b)) return false;
    for(int y = 0; y < a.height(); ++y)
        for(int x = 0; x < a.width(); ++x)
        {
            if(a.pixel(x, y) != b.pixel(x, y))
                return false;
        }
    return true;
}
bool isFlippedHorizontal(Image a, Image b)
{
    if(!isSameSize(a, b)) return false;
    int w = a.width();
    for(int y = 0; y < a.height(); ++y)
        for(int x = 0; x < a.width(); ++x)
        {
            if(a.pixel(x, y) != b.pixel(w - x - 1, y))
                return false;
        }
    return true;
}
bool isFlippedVertical(Image a, Image b)
{
    if(!isSameSize(a, b)) return false;
    int h = a.height();
    for(int y = 0; y < a.height(); ++y)
        for(int x = 0; x < a.width(); ++x)
        {
            if(a.pixel(x, y) != b.pixel(x, h - y - 1))
                return false;
        }
    return true;
}
bool isFlippedBoth(Image a, Image b)
{
    if(!isSameSize(a, b)) return false;
    int w = a.width();
    int h = a.height();
    for(int y = 0; y < a.height(); ++y)
        for(int x = 0; x < a.width(); ++x)
        {
            if(a.pixel(x, y) != b.pixel(w - x - 1, h - y - 1))
                return false;
        }
    return true;
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. If the image is not symmetric in some fashion, then you can probably just flip along different axes and do a quick comparison to check if any are non-equal.

```
def is_horizontally_flipped(orig, img):
    tst = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    return np.any(orig != tst)
```

Comment: that means I have to check all possible combination for getting perfect view according to orig image  like if I first flip it horizontally then vertical then how can I check

Comment: I think flipping the whole image for all possible combination is very expensive. Better you only "flip" the coordinates to compare the pixels.